# SolrNet - Using Dependency injection doesnt call the Startup.Init<T> method

Tags: dependency-injection, solr, solrnet, service-locator

Using Solrnet in my .NET core project through dependency injection as -

```
services.AddSolrNet<T>("http://localhost:8983/solr");
And injecting it through ISolrOperations<T>
```

As opposed to how we do in .net framework `Startup.Init<T>("http://localhost:8983/solr");`
This calls the `Startup.Init<T>` method and allows me to register my custom response parser at runtime which is not the case when I use depedency injection.

Any idea how to solve this ? I want to use DI but at run time, i wish to deregister default response parser and register my own. These lines work perfectly fine in .net framework -

```
SolrNet.Startup.Container.Remove<ISolrAbstractResponseParser<SolrResponse>>();
SolrNet.Startup.Container.Register<ISolrAbstractResponseParser<SolrResponse>>(c => new AggregateResponseParser<SolrResponse>(new ISolrAbstractResponseParser<SolrResponse>[]
                {
                        new ResultsNestedResponseParser<SolrResponse>(new SolrNestedDocumentParser<SolrResponse>(c.GetInstance<ISolrDocumentPropertyVisitor>()))
                }));
```